# Grafana derivative not showing right output values

Tags: elasticsearch, math, grafana

I put data values of a sinewave into elasticsearch and plotted it with grafana and set the derivative of the curve in the plot under it.

I was expecting to see a cos wave with the same amplitude, but I keep seeing a very flattened cos wave, the shift appears to be correct but the magnitude is all wrong, I am wondering what could be causing this? Have I configured grafana wrong?

This is the php script generating the curve:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

while(true)
{
    echo sin(deg2rad(time())) . " " . date('d M Y H:i:s') . "\n";
    sleep(1);
}
#echo sin(deg2rad(60));  //  0.866025403 ...
#echo sin(60);           // -0.304810621 ...

?>
```

I am using logstash to capture the value and timestamp and send it to elastic.
Thanks.

[image: Sinewave in grafana]

Answer (score 0):

If your function is

```
f(t) = sin(deg2rad(t)) = sin(t * pi / 180)
```

then the derivative is

```
f'(t) = pi / 180 * cos(t * pi / 180)
```

This factor is about `0.017`, which looks to be consistent with your plots.